# Error en función recursiva resolviendo un problema de inteligencia artificial

Tags: python, funciones, recursión, inteligencia-artificial

Estoy explorando conjuntos de programas en python que actúen como un sistema cognitivo de inteligencia artificial.
Estoy intentando resolver problemas de aritmética elemental como los de aquellos cuadernillos llamados Rubio.
El problema en cuestión es uno que dice: "Si tengo 3 manzanas en una mano y 1 manzana en la otra. ¿Cuántas manzanas tengo en total?
Antes de atacar el problema del procesamiento del lenguaje natural, el cual me parece demasiado complejo para abordarlo desde un primer momento, me centraré en darle una red semántica ya construida a mi sistema sobre la que pueda trabajar.
Para este problema la red sería la de la ilustración siguiente:
[image]

A continuación escribo mi código:

```
#Creo la clase nodo
class nodo(object):
        def __init__(nombre, nombrenodo, número):
                nombre.nombrenodo = nombrenodo
                nombre.número = número
                nombre.hijos = []

def añadir_hijo(nombre, obj):
    nombre.hijos.append(obj)

def hijosde(sujeto): #Esta función te da una lista con los hijo de un nodo
    listadehijos = []
    contador = 0
    while contador<len(sujeto.hijos):
        listadehijos.append(sujeto.hijos[contador])
        contador = contador + 1
    return listadehijos

#Esta es la función recursiva que me falla
def númerode(entidad,sujeto): 
    if sujeto.nombrenodo == entidad.nombrenodo:
        return(sujeto.número)
    else:
        número = 0
        a = hijosde(sujeto)
        while len(a)!=0:
            for b in a:
                número = número + númerode(entidad,b)
            a = hijosde(b)
        return número

#A continuación creo la red de nodos sobre la que la función "númerode" va a trabajar para averiguar el número de manzanas total
sujeto = nodo("sujeto",1)
mano1 = nodo("hand1",1)
manzana = nodo("manzana",3)
mano2=nodo("mano2",1)
manzana2=nodo("manzana",1)

añadir_hijo(sujeto, mano1)
añadir_hijo(mano1, manzana)
añadir_hijo(sujeto, mano2)
añadir_hijo(mano2, manzana2)
```

Si después de haber cargado el código introduzco númerode(manzana,sujeto), para que me saque el número de todas las manzanas que hay, me dá de resultado 5, en vez de 4. Parece que la rama sujeto-mano2-manzana la hace dos veces, entonces suma 3+1+1=5, no sé por qué hace esto. Si pruebas a ponerle númerode(manzana, mano1) te da 3 lo cuál es correcto, de la misma manera que si pones númerode(manzana,mano2) te da 1.
Por favor, ¿Puede alguien echar un vistazo a mi función recursiva "númerode"? No parece un problema muy complicado, ¿verdad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No termino de entender la necesidad del ciclo `while` en tu función, de hecho ocurre algo parecido a lo que dices (llamas dos veces a los hijos de `mano2`) por redefinir la lista `a` dentro del ciclo.

La función debe ir recorriendo el árbol y llamar a `hijosde` una sola vez por cada nodo, debería ser algo así:

```
def númerode(entidad,sujeto): 
    if sujeto.nombrenodo == entidad.nombrenodo:
        return(sujeto.número)
    else:
        número = 0
        for b in sujeto.hijos:
            número = número + númerode(entidad,b)
        return número
```

Que para tu ejemplo imprime 4.

Answer (score 0):

Tras ver como se hacen y se recorren los árboles en [este libro de python](https://argentinaenpython.com/quiero-aprender-python/aprenda-a-pensar-como-un-programador-con-python.pdf) (Aprenda a Pensarcomo un Programador con Python) , he decidido hacer primeramente una función que recorra mi red, que en resumidas cuentas, es un árbol

```
def imprimearbol(nodo): #Recorrido de un árbol
        if nodo == None: return
        print(nodo.nombrenodo)
        contador = 0
        while contador<len(nodo.hijos):
                imprimearbol(nodo.hijos[contador])
                contador = contador + 1
```

El código de esta función me ha inspirado a crear una función parecida pero que va ir sumando los números que coincidan con el nombre de la entidad.

```
def númerode(entidad,sujeto): #En el caso 2 entity es apple
    if entidad.nombrenodo == sujeto.nombrenodo : return sujeto.número
    número = 0
    contador = 0
    while contador<len(sujeto.hijos):
          número = número + númerode(entidad,sujeto.hijos[contador])
          contador = contador + 1
    return(número)
```

Y finalmente esta función hace la suma correcta de las manzanas si le introduces númerode(manzana,sujeto)

Comment: Ese código hace exactamente lo mismo que mi código pero usando un ciclo `while` y un contador para acceder a la lista mediante indice en vez de un `for_ in`. La idea es la misma, recorrer cada elemento de la lista de hijos, no obstante es más ineficiente usar un `while` + `contador` + `len` que la forma más natural y pythónica de un `for _ in`, es un código más genérico y aplicable a otros lenguajes pero no es la mejor opción en Python.  Saludos.

Comment: @FJSevilla: Gracias de nuevo, FJSevilla por tu aportación. En mi modo me ahorro la función "hijosde" que ya tiene contador dentro, así que si es por el número de contadores, nos quedamos igual

Comment: Ambas funciones pueden prescindir de `hijosde` y usar directamente el atributo `hijos` de la clase `nodo`. Esa no es realemnte la cuestión, simplemnte se trata de dos formas diferentes de recorrer una lista. He editado la respuesta para usar directamente el atributo `sujeto.hijos`. De hecho la función `hijosde` solo retorna una copia ineficiente de la lista `sujeto.hijos` por lo que carece de sentido. Usar un `while` para recorrer un iterable en python carece de sentido a no ser que implementemos ciertas condiciones de salida u otros escenarios especiales ya que la forma natural es un `for in`